# TeXnicCenter only offers an empty project

Tags: texniccenter

After clicking on "New Project" my TeXnicCenter only offers me an empty project, without any template. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my programm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had to change directories under: Tools -> Options -> Directories:

c:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\Templates\Projects\

for projects and the following for the documents:

c:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\Templates\Documents\